# numerical integration of two variable function over one variable only in C++ (using Numerical Recipes libraries)

Tags: c++, integration, numerical

I am programming in C++
I need to integrate a function of two variables, say f(x,y), over only one of the two:

I(y) = int f(x,y)dx

I'm using the libraries form Numerical Recipes. however, if I use quadrature.h routines, such as qsimp, qtrap, those are one-dimensional only; If instead I use quad3d.h, this contains the three-dimensional version only.

here's (a simplified version of) my code:

```
Doub NFW_rho(Doub variable,double angle) {
    return 1 / (pow(variable,2) + ... + cos(angle)) ;
}
int main ()
{
...
for (double angle = pi/36; angle < fi_max; angle += incr) {
    double min = D * cos(angle) - sqrt(pow(rt,2.) - pow(D * sin(angle),2.)) ;
    double max = D * cos(angle) + sqrt(pow(rt,2.) - pow(D * sin(angle),2.)) ;
...
Doub NFW_int = qsimp(NFW_rho,min,max) ;
double NFW = NFW_const * NFW_int ;
}
```

When compiling, I get an error message relative to the call to qsimp, stating that the call to qsimp is wrong (clearly, as NFW_rho is a 2D function).

Does any of you have a smart and simple way out?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the older C++, you had things like `std::bind2nd` that would give a new function object by "binding" the 2nd argument to a constant value provided; in C++11, it's just `std::bind` (which uses placeholders to denote what's still unbound).

So you might have something like

```
bind2nd(NFW_rho, 0.75); //older
bind(NFW_rho, _1, 0.75); //newer
```

where 0.75 is your angle (if you need different values of y as you go, you'll need to bind again). I've left off a lot of the `std::` stuff.